# Set a dynamic value/label on a command button

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have a command button within a visualforce component and I would like to allow the label on the command button to be dynamically passed through the component, for example:

**Component Attribute Declaration:**

```
<apex:attribute name="search" assignTo="{!searchLabel}" description="Text displayed on the form submission button" type="String" />
```

I thought after setting up the controller this would be as easy as adding this markup to my component:

**Component Command Button:**

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="{!SearchLabel}" action="{!Search}" styleClass="block"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

But unfortunately I get a command button with a blank value for its label. Any ideas as to why I'd get this result?

---

Here is my controller details in case that helps with solving the issue:

**Controller:**

```
public class MyController {

    public String searchLabel { get; set; }

    public MyController(){
        this.searchLabel = 'Search'; //default value
    }

    public String getSearchLabel(){
        /* this does not fire unless I set getter to private, 
        but even then "searchLabel" is NULL */

        return searchLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried removing the getSearchLabel function completely? Its not required since you have defined the getter and setter for searchLabel.

Comment: Yes I only added that after I ran into issues and as I mentioned unless I set the getter to private it doesn't fire anyways

Comment: try remove this and put debug in getmethod and remove get set of main variable.

Comment: It appears as though you're trying to do "constructor chaining" which you've not implemented correctly. See the Apex Developer Guide for more on that subject. Also look at use of the "This" keyword, which is an instance technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern does work. (In this example I'm passing the button action in too but that could instead come from the component's controller.)

Component:

```
<apex:component>
   <apex:attribute name="searchLabel" type="String" required="true" description="..."/>
   <apex:attribute name="searchAction" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true" description="..."/>
   <apex:commandButton value="{!searchLabel}" action="{!searchAction}"/>
</apex:component>
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="tmp">
<apex:form>
    <c:tmp searchLabel="{!searchLabel}" searchAction="{!searchAction}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class Tmp {
    public String getSearchLabel() {
        return 'Search';
    }
    public PageReference searchAction() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You don't say if your component has its own controller; if it doesn't then the `assignTo` makes little sense, and if it does first transferring the value to the component controller and then referencing it from there seems redundant. (See the [apex:attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_attribute.htm) documentation). I suspect the `assignTo` is the source of your problem.

Comment: I do have a controller yes, but considering I don't need to assign this to anything given the nature of what I'm doing, I went ahead and removed that (not sure why I didn't think of that at the time). Works great now, thanks!